# How to output PRINT message to a log file in Invoke-SqlCmd

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do redirect PRINT message from SQL script to output file via powershell 2.0 ? I tried the -verbose command, I can see the verbose message from powershell command line, but it doesn't write the message to output file.

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile $SqlFile -verbose | Out-File -filePath "D:\Output\Text.log
```